# Typeorm mysql cannot find by enum value

Tags: mysql, typeorm

this is my code

```ts
async findAdmin() {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ role: 0 });
    const user2 = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { role: 0 } });
    const users = await this.userRepository.find();
    console.log({ user, user2, users });
}
```

and this is my log output

```js
{
  user: undefined,
  user2: undefined,
  users: [
    User {
      id: 'a69c0fea-ff08-4fef-949f-3d2717571795',
      phoneNumber: '+989111111111',
      role: 0
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the problem here? why `user` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, you can find numeric enums with stringified value in mysql.

when you want to find `role: 1` it gets the first enum value (as index, not value)

so for no confusion I decided to use string enums.